# Close button disabled after sheet presentation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my cocoa app I need to login an user and show a table view. For now I've implemented the app as follow:

1. User insert username and password
2. User press login button
3. While user press login button, I send a request to a server to verify the account and if the user can access to the service it shows the view controller with table view

To show the view controller with table view I used the following code:

```
HistoryViewController *historyViewController = [[HistoryViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewControllerAsSheet:historyViewController];
```

When it shows me the view controller I saw that the close button (the red one) at the top left of the window become disabled. How I can keep it enabled after use the code I post before? Or how I can dismiss it?

Comment: If you are using modal session, close button will not be enabled. If you want to dismiss the sheet, you can know how to dismiss it based on how you presented it. If you can share the code used for  presentViewControllerAsSheet method, we can explain on how to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you would have figured it out by this time.  This message is for those who run into this post. It is by design that the close button will be disabled when the view controller is presented as sheet. On the presented controller, you need to have a button which can be wired up to dismiss the presented controller.